# Addition of rows in CSV File periodically

Tags: perl, dbi

[image]

**OVERVIEW:**
1. In Perl, I am using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel to write into Excel created CSV Files.
2. The data to be fed into the CSV File is being generated from Mysql queries.

**WHAT IS HAPPENING:**
1. The CSV is being generated.
2. Only one row's data is being processed into it.

**WHAT IS REQUIRED:**
1. Periodic addition of data in the form of rows, say every 30 seconds. 
It will therefore create a huge CSV File, daily. That means 2880 rows will be added in 24hrs.

The code is as under:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

# DEFINING THE DATE 
 ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year) =localtime(time);
undef $sec;
undef $hour;
undef $min;
$year += 1900;
$mday;
$mon+=1;
if ($mon < 10) {
        $mon = "0".$mon;
    }
if ($mday < 10) {
        $mday = "0".$mday;
    }

# CREATION OF A NEW WORKBOOK AND ADDITION OF A WORKSHEET
$tdate = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", $year, $mon, $mday);
$SubsLogFile = "Subscription-".$tdate;
$SubsLogFile .= ".csv";

my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new($SubsLogFile);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();


#=============================================

# FORMAT FOR THE HEADER
my $format = $workbook->add_format();
$format->set_bold();
$format->set_color('red');
$format->set_align('center');


# CREATION OF THE HEADER   
$worksheet->write(0, 0, "Sub Day", $format);
$worksheet->write(0, 1, "Sub Hour", $format);

#=============================================


###################
## SUBSCRIPTIONS ##
###################

# INPUTTING THE SERVER DETAILS
$db ="abcd";
$user = " abcd ";
$pass = " abcd ";
$host="100.100.100.100";
my $col = 2;



# GENERATING THE SQL QUERIES
$query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscription_detail WHERE creation_date >=CURRENT_DATE();";
 $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subscription_detail WHERE     DATE_FORMAT(creation_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H')  >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-    %m-%d %H');"; 

# CONNECTING TO THE SERVER
    $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$host", $user, $pass,{
      PrintError => 0,
      RaiseError => 0
  } ) or die "Can't connect to the database: $DBI::errstr\n";

$sqlQuery1  = $dbh->prepare($query1) or die "Can't prepare $query1: $DBI::errstr\n";
$sqlQuery2  = $dbh->prepare($query2) or die "Can't prepare $query2: $DBI::errstr\n"; 

# EXECUTING THE QUERIES
my $rv = $sqlQuery1->execute or die "can't execute the query: $DBI::errstr\n";
my $rv = $sqlQuery2->execute or die "can't execute the query: $DBI::errstr\n";

#=============================================

# OUTPUTING THE VALUES

while (@row= $sqlQuery1->fetchrow_array()) {
my $data1 = $row[0];
$worksheet->write($col, 0, "$data1");
};


while (@row= $sqlQuery2->fetchrow_array()) {
my $data2 = $row[0];
$worksheet->write($col, 1, "$data2");
};

# Close Workbook
$workbook->close();
```

#

Have checked the entire internet but got no solution or hint.
I have tried a lot of things like sleep 30, counters tec but it doesnt help.

Words of appreciation for any kind of help.. :)

Comment: What's your question?  What problems are you having?  "I want to go to Disney Land.  I have this car." does not tell me that you have a flat tire and don't know how to get the spare on.

Comment: "Have checked the entire internet". Wow! I bet that took a long time :-)

Comment: haha trust me Dave, have worked a lot trying to figure this thing off. 
nothing firm was concluded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question. For several reasons.

Are you trying to create a CSV file or an XLS file? If it's a CSV file then why are you using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel (which creates XLS files). If it's an XLS file, then why are you calling it ".csv"?

You seem to have two SQL queries in `$sqlQuery1` and `$sqlQuery2` which do pretty much the same thing.

Your calls to `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::write` seem to have the row and column parameters swapped around.

It looks like your code won't compile as you have `use strict` turned on, but you have a number of variables (`$sec`, `$min`, `$hour`, `$mday`, `$mon`, `$year` and many more) that aren't declared. This makes me think that we aren't actually seeing the code that you are running - which is a problem because the problem might well be in the code that you're not showing us.

Have you tried basic things like putting debugging output into the rows that fetch the data from the database? So you can be sure that data is being returned? Have you tried running your SQL queries on the database manually to ensure that they work as you expect?

Comment: Dave,
## 1. ## You are absolutely right in this matter. 
I certainly have to comment use strict and use warnings while running the code.

## 2. ## Spreadsheet::WriteExcel creates .csv as well as .xls file.
My requirement being a .csv.

## 3. ## There are many more mysql queries like such. They have not been put up which would elongate the code and create confusions.

## 4. ## All queries are running absolutely fine. 

## 5. ## The file is also being created. 
## 6. ## All that is required is : Addition of data (rows) every 30 seconds. (The count(*) from the mysql query).
## 7. ## Thank You :)

Comment: "I certainly have to comment use strict and use warnings while running the code". Then I highly recommend fixing your code so that you don't have to comment out `strict` and `warnings` before running it.

Comment: yeah Dave, i will. But that is no solution.

Comment: "Spreadsheet::WriteExcel creates .csv as well as .xls file". I think you're wrong there. I can find no reference in the documentation to Spreadsheet::WriteExcel creating CSV files. To write a CSV file, use Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS.

Comment: one moment, let me show you the file that gets created :) Ill put up a screenshot of the same.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with Dave, using Perl modules which interact with Excel in order to edit files in the simple text format that is CSV is like on a hot day rather than using a fan to create a breeze, building a rollercoaster and riding it continuously.

If the interface of Text::CSV is daunting, may I recommend my [Tie::Array::CSV](http://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) or there are many other modules that can build CSV for you with much less headache.

Answer (score 0):

This is not way to simply add new row into existing Excel file but:

1. You can use **Win32::OLE** to add data into existing Excel file directly
   (but you need to have Excel installed).
2. Or you need to *parse existing file* with **Spreadsheet::ParseExcel**, rename
   it, and next create new file with **Spreadsheet::WriteExcel** (with new
   rows).

Comment: Thanks Gangabass, 
Can Spreadsheet::WriteExcel be implemented with Win32::OLE?

PS. Sorry, am less reputed, cant vote up your answer. lol.

Comment: Or do #2 in one step with [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel/SaveParser.pm)

Comment: So, i will have to rename the file every 30 secs (ofcourse through thte code)?
Can you please assist me wririting a few lines of code? 
Thanks :)